# Variable declaration and scope in C#

Tags: c#, class, scope

I'm new to C# and have some trouble with the variable scope.

```
 if(number > 10)
 {
      int someNr = 5;
 }
 else
 {
      /* .... */
 }

 if(number2 < 50)
 {
      someNr = 10; /* PRODUCES AN ERROR */
 }
 else
 {
     /* ........ */
 }
```

I know that if number is not > 10 then someNr will not be declared as int. But should I wrote two times int someNr? What if both `if` are true? Double declaration? Is this a problem should I declare the variable outside the `if`?

Class variables

```
PHP

class TEST {
   private $test = 'test';

   private function testVariable(){
       /* Not declared */
       echo $test;
   }

   private function testVariable2(){
       /* echo 'test' */
       echo $this->test;
   }
}

C#

class TEST {
   private string test = "test";

   private void testVariable(){
       /* takes the value of class variable test */
       test;
   }

   private function testVariable2(){
       /* takes also the value of class variable 'test' */
       this.test;
   }
}
```

But what if

```
C#

class TEST {
   private string test = "test";

   private void testVariable(){
       string test = "somethingOther";

       Console.WriteLine(test);
   }
}
```

test is "test" or "somethingOther"?

Which has the priority? The class variable or the local-method variable?

Comment: Why don't you test it with some simple codes? Would be faster than waiting for answers...

Comment: I'll do that, but I'm sure that I'll have extra knowledge with some answers!

Comment: @developerwjk Is this comment constructive? It is obvious for you... maybe not for me. The purpose of SO is to ask question, but as I can see I get only negative comments and -2 rating... maybe is this place only for pro whom is all "obvious"...

Comment: Obvious in the sense that spending 2 seconds to "run" in Visual Studio will give you the answer, so yes, yes it is.

Comment: I just wanted to know why PHP doesn't take the class scope if the variable is not redeclared inside a method, and C# do... This is the differnce I wanted to know more, and maybe I could learn something other with a good answer. Sure VS tell me the value, but cannot explain me where is the difference between PHP and C#. But if this is not allowed here, I would delete my question so nobody gets hurt by a obvious quesion...

Comment: This was not the point (and BTW from what I know you should never use the `global` keywork in `PHP`). I re-ask my question: what is the sense of using `this.classVariable` inside a function instead of classVariable if classVariable is already a "global scope" variable?

Comment: @developerwjk: If it were obvious to the OP then the question would not have been asked. Everyone was a beginner once, including you. There was a day when you did not know the answer to this question and then a following day when you did; today is that day for the OP.

Comment: @developerwjk: Your logic in your last comment there is fallacious. There is no logical connection between a compiled language and a language which requires declaration of storage. You can have interpreted languages that require declaration, and compiled languages which do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the variable inside an `if` statement you should declare it outside the `if` statement, otherwise it will be a local variable only available inside the `if` statement:

```
int someNr;
if(number > 10)
{
  someNr = 5;
}
else
{
  /* .... */
}

if(number2 < 50)
{
  someNr = 10;
}
else
{
  /* ........ */
}
```

Note: You also need to set some value to the variable in the `else` blocks, or set an initial value when you define it, otherwise it's not known to always have a value.

---

In your class `TEST` the local variable will shadow the class member:

```
class TEST {
  private string test = "test"; // this is a member of the class

  private void testVariable(){
    string test = "somethingOther"; // this is a local variable that shadows the class member

    Console.WriteLine(test); // this will use the local variable, it can't see the class member
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your first example produces an error, because `someNr` is only defined within the scope of the `if` statement.  You must re-define it in your second `if`, declaring it as an `int`.

In your second example, the correct syntax would be `Console.WriteLine(test);`.  Your output would be 'somethingOther', as the `test` in the inner scope will be used.

Comment: What if a declare to times someNr inside the two `if`? Error both `if` are true?
So innerscope has the priority?

Comment: inner scope has priority.  `someNr` only exists within the scope it is declared.  It's valid if you declare them both correctly

Comment: if you want *someNr* to be in scope for both (or more) *if* statements, then you should declare it within the method (so outside of the *if* statements) or even the class to give it scope over the entire class.

Comment: To clarify, the variable is in scope within *the consequence block*, not within the entire `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Example of Method Scope** -- variable `someNr` is declared within the method (along with `number2`) and is therefore accessible throughout the method:

```
public class IntegersTestScope
{
    public void TestIntegers(int number)
    {
        int number2 = 0;
        int someNr = 0;

        number2 += number;

        if (number > 10)
        {
            someNr = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            /* .... */
        }

        if (number2 < 50)
        {
            someNr = 10; /* This will no longer PRODUCE AN ERROR */
        }
        else
        {
            /* ........ */
        }

        Console.WriteLine("someNr={0}", someNr.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Example of Class Scope** -- variable `_someNr` is declared within the class and are therefore accessible to all methods with that class (Note: variable `_someNr` is prefixed with underscore character '_' as a naming convention only to denote variable global to class and is not required for code to work):

```
public class IntegersTestScope
{
    private int _someNr = 0;

    public void TestIntegers(int number)
    {
        int number2 = 0;

        number2 += number;

        if (number > 10)
        {
            _someNr = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            /* .... */
        }

        if (number2 < 50)
        {
            _someNr = 10; /* This will no longer PRODUCE AN ERROR */
        }
        else
        {
            /* ........ */
        }

        Console.WriteLine("someNr={0}", _someNr.ToString());
    }
}
```